# Dealing with categorical variables - Looking for recommendations

Tags: categorical-data, python, scikit-learn, categorical-encoding

I have the following dataset, in which the wind direction (`Direccion del viento (Pos)`) column is categorical, with 8 categorical values:

[image]

In total **Direccion del viento (Pos)** it has 8 categories:

- SO - Sur oeste
- SE - Sur este
- S - Sur
- N - Norte
- NO - Nor oeste
- NE - Nor este
- O - Oeste
- E - Este

Then, I convert this dataframe to numpy array and I get:

```
direccion_viento_pos
dtype: bool
[['S']
 ['S']
 ['S']
 ...
 ['SO']
 ['NO']
 ['SO']]
```

Since I have character string values, I want these to be numeric values, so I need to code the categorical variables. That is, we code the text values into numerical values.

Then I perform two activities:

1. I use `LabelEncoder()` to simply encode the values into number according to how many categories I have.

Label encoding is simply converting each value in a column to a number

```
labelencoder_direccion_viento_pos = LabelEncoder()
direccion_viento_pos[:, 0] = labelencoder_direccion_viento_pos.fit_transform(direccion_viento_pos[:, 0])
```

2. I use `OneHotEncoder` to convert each category value into a new column and assigns a 1 or 0 (True/False) value to the column:

```
    onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
    direccion_viento_pos = onehotencoder.fit_transform(direccion_viento_pos).toarray()
```

which gives me these new values:

```
direccion_viento_pos
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Then I convert this `direccion_viento_pos` array to a dataframe to more easily visualize it:

```
# Turn array into dataframe with columns indexes
cols = ['E', 'N', 'NE', 'NO', 'O', 'S', 'SE', 'SO']
df_direccion_viento = pd.DataFrame(direccion_viento_pos, columns=cols)
```

[image]

Then, I can get by each category value a new column and assigns a 1 or 0 (True/False) value to the column.

**If I use** [pandas.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) **function I get the same result.**

My question is:
Is this the best way of dealing with these categorical variables?
Having a column for each category and having values of zeros in several of them does not help to have a bias or noise in the data for when automatic learning algorithms are applied?

I’ve recently started reading about it in [this article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/), but any guidance on this I appreciate

Comment: This question cannot be answered unless you tell us what you're then feeding the categorical data into: classification or regression? Regression-based, tree-based, NN-based, clustering...? Are you combining the wind direction with a numerical variable like (say) wind speed? What exactly are you trying to predict or regress?

Comment: As to `LabelEncoder()`, it'll simply encode the levels into arbitrary (essentially random) numbers according to how many times each level occurred. You'd get something similar if you did a random shuffle on the numerical levels.

Comment: I don't understand this part *"Having a [one-hot] column for each category and having values of zeros in several of them does not help to have a bias or noise in the data for when automatic learning algorithms are applied?"* If the most common wind direction is S(outh)/S(ur), then that's simply what it is. That's not 'noise', it's information. And when you say 'bias', are you asking whether one-hot values can or should be normalized, like numerical variables, for regression? (The answer is no). But that doesn't address whether you need to be using one-hot encoding in the first place.

Comment: @smci I agree that some idea of purpose would help here, but whether wind direction is a response or a predictor is secondary to the main point: these are not really categorical data.

Comment: The problem with this post is that although it tells us a lot about how you are processing your data, it says nothing about your statistical problem, which is mentioned only in passing as "dealing" with the variables.  That is the kind of detail it needs to be answerable.

Comment: bgarcial, the question could do with a more accurate title, re "circular data". Also, there are several hits on CV for [*circular data wind*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=circular+data+wind)

Answer (score 5):

The premise is incorrect and the elaborate riff on how to tackle this in Python code is thus  misdirected.

Wind direction reported this way may *seem* categorical, but underneath the 8 letter codes are just compass directions, which in degrees are 0 for North in steps of 45 to 315 as North-West, 360 being North again. (Anyone preferring to think in radians is more than welcome, not least because that is likely to be what you need to feed to your software in any case.)

In particular, the directions are not just different, as arbitrary categories are. They represent points on a quantitative scale, as (e.g.) North is certainly closer to North-West and North-East than it is to any other direction. Thus we have **circular data**, one class of **directional data**. It's true that almost no general texts or courses even mention directional data, and people can have fruitful statistical careers without ever meeting them, but there is a distinct literature on the topic.

It is quite wrong to treat such directions as merely categorical. You would be losing much of the information. If they are predictors, working with the sine and cosine of the direction is a good idea.

General purpose encoders, in Python or any other software, naturally will know nothing whatsoever about this circular scale.

The coarseness of the measurement (45$^\circ$ bins) need not inhibit, let alone prohibit, treating the directions numerically. I've used compass directions this coarse in published work.

(Ordered categorical scales with circular order don't often get mentioned in sermons on measurement scales, but try day of the week and the seasons spring, summer, autumn (fall), winter as examples evident from childhood. These particular examples are also examples that could be considered equally spaced. That doesn't rule out extra flavour, as whenever particular days of the week have further implications. )

Comment: Ordered categoricals are categoricals, too. The only difference here is it's circular as well as ordered. It's easy to define a circular distance or angle function as the minimum of both angles, modulo-8. We don't know enough to conclude *"It is quite wrong to treat them as merely categorical"*. If we are taking interaction terms (e.g. wind-direction x wind-speed, or wind-direction x smog/particulates), then one-hotting or binning could potentially be the best treatment - we don't know unless the OP tells us what they're doing, statistically.

Comment: (Btw, the direction has already been quantized into 8 very coarse bins. It's not like we have angle data to the nearest 1º or 10º. In that case sines and cosines might be more useful.)

Comment: @smci Really not so. See https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/annals-of-glaciology/issue/0B689F00CF418B9AE78528D3CE1A76F2 for one specific example in which similar data were used (fruitfully, in my view, but I am second author) or any text on circular data which includes examples of similarly coarse data. Naturally, I agree that finer bins are preferable when the precision isn't spurious. Classification of directions and interaction terms? Never seen either of them discussed in principle or in practice, although naturally my experience is finite too.

Comment: Days of the week or seasons are equally spaced on a circle too, and sometimes that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you plan to do with the data. There are various ways to work with categorical variables as it's indicated in the article you suggested. You need to pick the more appropriate for the model/situation you are working on by investigating if the approach you are taking is right for the model you are using.

Talking specifically about *hot-encoding*, it is not always needed. Decision tree models can handle categorical values without hot-encoding (depends on implementation, *H2O* implementation doesn't requires it, but the widely used *sickit-learn* implementation do requires it).

Hot encoding can be actually bad for tree decision models as the sparsity added by the new variables inserted is very likely to cause actual numerical features to have higher feature importance.

You can read more about this [here](https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/).

Comment: Hi Roberto, what is the difference between using `OneHotEncoder` (sklearn) class and use `pandas.get_dummies` I get the same result. Another inquiry that I have is, the two problems of use one-hot-encoding on tree-based models, still persist on generalized linear models?

Comment: I am exploring H20, this platform can support me on test some  models and check your behavior really?

Comment: _pandas.get_dummies_ converts strings only. _OneHotEncoder_ is the opposite, it only works with integers. Both should give you the same result as they are doing the same thing, just on different input types.

Yes, you can give _H2O_ a try, but it's really context dependant on what you are trying to do ;)

Comment: The disvantages of one hot encoding on tree-based models also are presented on other lineal models like Neural Networks or regressions or clustering ?

Comment: (Late to this party) Good advice in general, but misses the point under this particular example.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Nick's answer:

I absolutely agree that wind directions should not be just taken as ordinary categorical variables, as that absolutes discards the similarities between different directions. Also, without knowing what you intend to do with your data, it is impossible to say which encoding is best for your application.

However, if you don't want to go the full route with treating this data as directional and to deal with the resulting complexity of the circular data ($2\pi=0$), there is a different encoding that still retains some of the similarity within the "categories":

You can simply encode any of the categories depending on which of the letters N,E,S,W appears in them. So your coding scheme would be something like:

```
N  -> 1,0,0,0
NE -> 1,1,0,0
E  -> 0,1,0,0
SE -> 0,1,1,0
S  -> 0,0,1,0
SW -> 0,0,1,1
W  -> 0,0,0,1
NW -> 1,0,0,1
```

(depending on your encoding you could also try using $0.5$ or $1/\sqrt{2}$ for those lines with two entries unequal to 0, but this depends on the application).

With that encoding, you retain part of the actual structure of the data (NE and N have similar coding, as do NE and NW) but you don't need to use actual circular data.

**EDIT**:

After thinking about this a bit more, I noticed that I messed up the actual coding. It should be something like this:

```
N  -> 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
NE -> 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
E  -> 0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
SE -> 0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
S  -> 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0
SW -> 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0
W  -> 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
NW -> 1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
```

so all codes have the same number of 1s.

If this is useful, depends on the actual application. With sin/cos of the angles you get that some of the entries are negatives of each other, which may make sense if you can e.g. treat "N" as the negative of "S". If "N" and "S" are just two different things, that should not be related except by being different, a coding like the above can perform better. This depends on domain knowledge.

Comment: This way adjacent wind directions differ by 1 bit but otherwise pairs of directions don't equally convey difference on the circle. I find it hard to see why anyone would prefer this awkward coding when sines and cosines preserve the information perfectly.

Comment: ... or angles for that matter.

Comment: @NickCox Urgs, you are right. I messed up the actual idea of this coding. I agree that sin/cos may be correct for some applications, but in other cases, the relationship between opposite directions is not what is needed. WIth angles, it is hard to represent that $0$ is close to $2\pi$. I used this kind of coding before with monthly data and it worked much better than just using sin/cos (July is not just a negative January) or Fourier regression (overfitting). But it depends on the application, and I don't know much about meterology.

Comment: In economic data, seasonality is often not smooth e.g.. December can see spikes in expenditure. So economists often just use indicator variables for months rather than sines and cosines. But winds follow the laws of physics. As others have pointed out, the issues in this thread range from how are the data best represented to what the OP wants to do. I don't follow why $0$ being close to (strictly, equal to)  $2\pi$ is hard to follow, unless you are meeting angles on the circle for the first time (which everyone does who meets them at all).

Comment: For wind directions, and for directions in the natural environment generally, North really is the opposite of South. In any case, your codings represent each value with 8 new values; mine uses one, namely angle; further use of sines and cosines can be parsimonious and is a matter of convenience.

Comment: @NickCox Ok, misunderstanding: I did not mean to imply that thinking of $2\pi$ and $0$ as similar is hard, rather that it is problematic to include is models. If you just put $0$ and $2\pi$ into linear regression, then it will not treat them as the same, but rather treat one as very high and the other as very low (hence the need to recode). If this or the other coding is better, I cannot tell, because I neither know the modeling goal nor do I have enough domain knowledge. E.g. does the chance of hurricanes increase with wind coming from south and decrease with it coming from the north?

Comment: Sines and cosines are, again, the answer. Using angle as if it were a linear predictor is, as you imply, not just a bad idea but also a recipe for nonsense. https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0116 is one tutorial review of a standard approach. In nature, if one direction is optimal the opposite direction is usually pessimal, but nature can be complicated too.

Comment: @NickCox I think we have some misunderstanding: a) I didn't mean to imply that using angles in a linear model is a good idea, quite the opposite. b) I didn't mean to imply that my coding is better than yours per se. I don't know which one is better, because I do not have enough domain knowledge. Yours might be better, if your assumptions are met, mine might be better (the fixed one of course) if my assumptions are met. Which assumptions are correct? I do not know, and I don't think it makes much sense to discuss this point. Neither of us knows the question at hand, so we can't know.

Comment: I agree with you in not wanting to be confrontational here. But yes; I have domain knowledge and in particular have often, over 40 years, analysed wind direction data, and many other circular datasets from environmental science and indeed elsewhere. That makes me confident in my judgement about how best to deal with wind drections, but I hope it does not make me appear dogmatic or obnoxious.  But I don't think that not knowing what the OP wants is as fatal as you think, as for any conceivable purpose mapping wind direction to angle is the best thing to do.

Comment: @NickCox I read the paper, so I agree you do have domain knowledge. But still, without knowing the question, it is just an educated guess (more educated in your case than in mine, agreed) to say which coding is best. There is a tendency in many statistical analyses to just use the standard assumptions, and then stick with them, which can sometimes lead to bad analyses, if those assumptions are not met. E.g. what if the goal is to predict if Vianne Rocher will move on any day (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolat_(2000_film))? Angles won't work well in that case, at least.

Comment: Surprise: statistics can't illuminate all problems.